# add view with user:id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to add a view to the Users/views, which will incorporate the users-id.  The view I'm looking to add is 'test' and I'd like each User to have their own test page.  For example, the path for User edit is as follows: http://localhost:3000/users/1/edit.  I have no problem creating a test page, but can't get it to associate with user:id.  I'd like the User test path to be as follows: http://localhost:3000/users/1/test.  Unsure how to set this up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a route called http://localhost:3000/users/1/test, you should create a member on your resources users.

So in your routes you'll have to add something like this:

```
resources :users do 
  get :test, on: :member
end
```

(For reference, also see the rails guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

*Note: with the on: :member option. You get the resource id in the params[:id]. If you don't specify it like this, you'll find it the params[:user_id].*

When you've done that, you should add the action to your controller and create the corresponding view.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def test
    # create a corresponding view app/views/users/test.html.erb
  end
end
```

Comment: that's it! Thank you!

Comment: You should note that `params[:id]` becomes `params[:user_id]` in this `test` action

Comment: @RichPeck could you elaborate? 

According to the rails guides section "2.10.1 Adding Member Routes". The resource id is passed in params[:id]. I guess your thinking of the route without the 'on: :member' option. This will make the resource id available in the params[:user_id]. However, this is not the case in the example here above.

Comment: oh snap I think you're right. Thanks for clarifying this for me :)

Comment: It's good you've pointed it out though. It's a subtle thing that could be overlooked. I'll update the answer and leave a note about this. :)